How to render nodes incrementally using cytoscapejs' layout method?
I am currently using cytoscapejs for my UI to render a graph. I have a big graph that I want to render on-demand or incrementally to avoid performance bottleneck issues. My server sends the graphs in chunks as and when requested.
What I want to do:

Fetch the first chunk from the backend and render it with dagre layout or any layout that is easier for the user to understand. We can call this graph as G0
Fetch the next chunk when the user requests neighbouring subgraph. (Assume that the size of the subgraph is fixed as of now) The fetched graph can be referred as G1
Render G1 with respect to G0 such that the overall result is consistent and looks like as if both G1 and G0 were rendered together.

What is happening:
When I render the G1 graph using the answer given on this page: Cytoscape: apply layout only to newly added nodes
the new nodes overlap the nodes of G0. In other words, the layout function is not taking the previously rendered graph G0 into consideration.
What have I tried:
I looked around and came across this library: https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-layout-utilities?tab=readme-ov-file which has been developed for the exact same purpose (incrementing layout adjustments). But when I tried this library (by referencing demo.html, I did not get the expected results. The nodes of G1 still overlap G0 nodes. Here is the snippets of my code:

The api initialisation:

 api = cy.layoutUtilities({
                desiredAspectRatio: 1.0,
                polyominoGridSizeFactor: 1.0,
                utilityFunction: 1,
                componentSpacing: 80
            })


Rendering the initial chunks (3 chunks):

        async function loadInitialChunks() {
            for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                // this function fetches an object containing two arrays
                // {nodes, edges} and stores it in a variable `preloadedchunks`
                await getChunk(chunkIndex++, chunkSize); 
            }
            renderChunks();
        }

        function renderChunks() {

            preloadedChunks.forEach(chunk => {
                chunk.nodes.forEach(node => {
                    cy.add({
                        group: 'nodes',
                        data: node.data,
                        position: node.position
                    });
                });
                cy.add(chunk.edges);
            });

           // This code has been referred from the demo.html file I mentioned above
           // More specifically, this code is present at line 299 in demo.html 
            var subgraphs = []
            cy.$().forEach(chunk => {
                var subgraph = {}
                subgraph.nodes = []
                subgraph.edges = []
                chunk.nodes().forEach(node => {
                    var boundingBox = node.boundingBox();
                    subgraph.nodes.push({
                        x: boundingBox.x1,
                        y: boundingBox.y1,
                        width: boundingBox.w,
                        height: boundingBox.h
                    })
                });

                chunk.edges().forEach(edge => {
                    subgraph.edges.push({
                        startX: edge.sourceEndpoint().x,
                        startY: edge.sourceEndpoint().y,
                        endX: edge.targetEndpoint().x,
                        endY: edge.targetEndpoint().y
                    })
                });
                subgraphs.push(subgraph);
            })

            var result = api.packComponents(subgraphs, true);
            cy.$().forEach((component, index) => {
                component.nodes().layout({
                    name: 'fcose',
                    animate: 'true',
                    fit: false,
                    transform: (node) => {
                        let position = {};
                        position.x = node.position('x') + result.shifts[index].dx;
                        position.y = node.position('y') + result.shifts[index].dy;
                        return position;
                    }
                }).run();
            });

            let currentZoom = cy.zoom();
            let currentPan = cy.pan();

            const layout = cy.layout({
                name: 'fcose',
                avoidOverlap: true,
                nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: true
            });
            layout.run();

        }    



Requesting additional chunks:

function renderAdditionalChunks(chunk, chunkIndex) {
            try {
                // This approach is given at line #398 in the demo.html file
                var newNodes = cy.collection();
                chunk.nodes.forEach(node => {
                    if (!loadedNodes.has(node.data.id)) {
                        node.data.chunkId = chunkIndex
                        var newEles = cy.add({
                            group: 'nodes',
                            data: node.data,
                        });
                        newNodes.merge(newEles.nodes());
                        loadedNodes.add(node.data.id);

                    }
                });

                chunk.edges.forEach(edge => {
                    edge.data.chunkId = chunkIndex
                    cy.add({
                        group: 'edges',
                        data: edge.data,

                    });
                });
                let elementF = cy.elements("node[chunkId=" + chunkIndex + "],edge[chunkId=" + chunkIndex + "]");
                console.log("Elements filtered out: ", elementF)

                elementF.layout({
                    name: 'fcose',
                    // fit: false,
                    animate: true,
                    avoidOverlap: true,
                    nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: true
                }).run();

                api.placeNewNodes(newNodes);

                cy.zoom(currentZoom);
                cy.pan(currentPan);

            } catch (error) {
                console.log(chunk)
                console.error('Error:', error);
            }

        }

It would be really great if anyone can help me figure out what am I missing here or if there are any other better alternatives to do so. Thanks.

I think you should first call api.placeNewNodes(newNodes); and then apply layout with randomize: false option. placeNewNodes function will place the nodes to appropriate positions considering the existing graph and then layout will refine their positions by respecting the existing layout (using randomize: false is important for this, otherwise it may generate a totally different layout).
